# table Total column results missing certain values

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vbscript

While running an sql server 2005 query on an asp.net page and attempting to total the values at the bottom of the values table, I have noticed that the total value is leaving out the values below which I have noted in bold which correspond to small result #'s occurring during weekends.  I cannot figure out why these values are left out.  I assumed it was a rounding issue in the convert unit (int, dbl, etc) and tried changing between different conversions with no success

(I am a beginner and inherited preexisting code to work with, so please assume I know little in any response).  Since I cannot attach a screenshot of the output, I have only copied one column of data as an example.  All help appreciated, thanks!

Shipped Date:   Total Shippers:

2/2/2015    249

2/3/2015    254

2/4/2015    255

2/5/2015    263

2/6/2015    209

2/7/2015    **6**

2/9/2015    322

2/10/2015   304

2/11/2015   270

2/12/2015   212

2/13/2015   205

2/14/2015   **2**

Totals: 2543

```html
<%@ Language="VBScript" %>
<% Option Explicit %>
<%
 Response.Expires = 0

 dim D1
  D1 = Request.Form("D1")
 dim D2
  D2 = Request.Form("D2")


 dim DispResults
  DispResults = Request.Form("A")

 dim TotalShippers, TotalShipperLines, TotalQuantityShipped, TotalKitsShipped, IntlTotalShippers, IntlTotalShipperLines, IntlTotalQuantityShipped, IntlTotalKitsShipped, GrandTotalShippers, GrandTotalShipperLines, GrandTotalQuantityShipped, GrandTotalKitsShipped
 IF D1 = "" THEN
  D1 = Month(Date()) & "/" & "1" & "/" & Year(Date())
 ELSE
 END IF

 IF D2 = "" THEN
  D2 = Date
 ELSE
 END IF

 
%>
<html>

<head>
<title>Daily Shipping Log</title>
<style>
body  {
 font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial;
 font-size: 16px;
}
select {
 font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial;
 font-size: 16px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body onLoad="document.Search.D1.focus()">
<center>
<img src="logo.jpg" ALT="Daily Shipping Log">

<br>

<form action="default.asp" method="POST" name="Search">
<input type=hidden name="A" value="1">

<table>
 <tr>
  <td align="center" valign="top">
   <table>

    <tr>
     <td align="center" valign="bottom">
      Enter Starting Date:&nbsp;
     </td>
     <td align="center" valign="bottom">
      <input type="text" name="D1" size="24" value="">
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td align="center" valign="bottom">
      Enter Ending Date:&nbsp;
     </td>
     <td align="center" valign="bottom">
      <input type="text" name="D2" size="24" value="">
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan=2 align="center" valign="bottom">
      <input type="submit" value="Generate Report">
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
  <td align="center" valign="top">
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td align="center" valign="top" style="background-color:#FFFF99; font-size:10px;">
      <b>Note:</b><br><br>
      Date formats must be in the following manner:<br><br>
      <b>MM/DD/YY</b> if using a 2-digit Month and Day.<br>
      <b>M/D/YY</b> is using a 1-digit Month or Day.<br><br>
      Other date formats will not return any records.
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

</form>

<br>
<%

IF D1 = "" THEN
ELSEIF DispResults = 1 THEN
 Response.Write "Data Reported is for Date Range:&nbsp;<b>" & D1 & "</b> to <b>" & D2 & "</b><br>"
 Response.Write "<hr color=""#65035A"" size=2 width=""100%"">"
 Response.Write "<table cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0 border=1 bordercolor=#666666>"
 Response.Write "<tr align=center>" 
 Response.Write "<td><b>Domestic:</b>"
 Response.Write "</td><td><b>International:</td></tr>"
 Response.Write "<tr align=center valign=top>"
 Response.Write "<tr align=center>"
 Response.Write "<td>"
 Response.Write "<table cellpadding=5>"
 Response.Write "<tr align=center valign=top>" 
 Response.Write "<td>"
 Response.Write "<b>Shipped Date:</b>"
 Response.Write "</td>"
 Response.Write "<td>"
 Response.Write "<b>Total Shippers:</b>"
 Response.Write "</td>"
 Response.Write "<td>"
 Response.Write "<b>Total Line Items Shipped:</b>"
 Response.Write "</td>"
 Response.Write "<td>"
 Response.Write "<b>Total Quantity Items Shipped:</b>"
 Response.Write "</td>"
 Response.Write "<td>"
 Response.Write "<b>Configured Kits Shipped:</b>"
 Response.Write "</td></tr>"


 dim oConn, oRS, oRS2
 Set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 oConn.Open """
 Set oRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
 Set oRS2 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

 oRS.open "Select s.ShipDate, Count(distinct CASE when s.country='USA' then l.ShipmentNo end) as TotalShippers, " & _
   "count(case when s.country='USA' then convert(int,l.ShipmentLineNo) END) as TotalLinesShipped, " & _
   "sum(case when s.country='USA' then (l.TotalShippedQuantity) else 0 END) as TotalItemsShipped, " & _
   "Count(distinct CASE when s.country<>'USA' then l.ShipmentNo end) as IntlTotalShippers, " & _
   "count(case when s.country<>'USA' then convert(int,l.ShipmentLineNo) END) as IntlTotalLinesShipped, " & _
   "sum(case when s.country<>'USA' then (l.TotalShippedQuantity) END) as IntlTotalItemsShipped, " & _
   "Count(distinct l.ShipmentNo) as GrandTotalShippers, " & _
   "convert(int, count(l.ShipmentLineNo)) as GrandTotalLinesShipped, " & _
   "sum(l.TotalShippedQuantity) as GrandTotalItemsShipped " & _
   "From shipments s, shipments_li l " & _
   "Where (s.ShipDate between '" & D1 & "' AND '" & D2 & "') " & _
   "and  s.ShipmentNo = l.ShipmentNo " & _
   "and l.TotalShippedQuantity>0 and s.status<>'X' AND " & _
   "s.shipfrominventory not in ('BI','CI','CS','IT')" & _
   " Group by s.ShipDate order by s.ShipDate", oConn
 
 
 DO WHILE NOT oRS.EOF
 Response.Write "<tr align=center><td>" & oRS("ShipDate") & "</td>"
 Response.Write "<td>" & oRS("TotalShippers").value & "</td>"
 Response.Write "<td>" & oRS("TotalLinesShipped").value & "</td>"
 Response.Write "<td>" & oRS("TotalItemsShipped").value & "</td>"
 
 oRS2.open "SELECT s.ShipDate, count(case when s.country='USA' THEN (l.ShipmentLineNo) end) AS CountOfKits, " & _
    "count(case when s.country<>'USA' THEN (l.ShipmentLineNo) end) AS IntlCountOfKits, " & _ 
           "count(l.ShipmentLineNo) AS GrandTotalCountOfKits " & _
    "FROM (shipments s INNER JOIN shipments_li l ON s.ShipmentNo = l.ShipmentNo) " & _
    "WHERE (l.TotalShippedQuantity>0) AND (s.Status<>'x') " & _
    "AND s.ShipDate='" & oRS("ShipDate").Value & "' " & _
    "AND (Left(l.partNo,5)<>'hires') AND (l.PartDescription<>'CHARGER KIT, AURIA') " & _
    "AND (Left(l.partNo,8) NOT IN ('303-M220' , '303-M218','303-M219')) " & _
    "AND (Left(l.partNo,4)<>'zeni') AND (Left(l.partNo,2)<>'sw') and (Left(l.partNo,7)<>'sr3upus')" & _ 
    "and l.Configuration is not null AND  s.shipfrominventory not in ('BI','CI','CS','IT')" & _
    "GROUP BY s.ShipDate " & _
    "ORDER By s.ShipDate", oConn

IF oRS2.EOF THEN Response.Write "<td>" & 0 & "</td></tr>" ELSE 
DO WHILE NOT oRS2.EOF
 Response.Write "<td>" & oRS2("CountOfKits").Value & "</td></tr>"
 TotalKitsShipped = CInt(oRS2("CountofKits").Value) + TotalKitsShipped
  
 TotalShippers = CInt(oRS("TotalShippers").Value) + TotalShippers
 TotalShipperLines = CInt(oRS("TotalLinesShipped").Value) + TotalShipperLines
 TotalQuantityShipped = CInt(oRS("TotalItemsShipped").Value) + TotalQuantityShipped
  

 oRS2.MoveNext
 Loop
 oRS2.Close

 oRS.MoveNext
 Loop
 oRS.Close

 Set oRS2 = Nothing   
 Set oRS = Nothing
 oConn.Close
 Set oConn = Nothing 

 Response.Write "<tr align=center><td><b>Totals:</b></td>"
 Response.Write "<td><b>" & TotalShippers & "</b></td>"
 Response.Write "<td><b>" & TotalShipperLines & "</b></td>"
 Response.Write "<td><b>" & TotalQuantityShipped & "</b></td>"
 Response.Write "<td><b>" & TotalKitsShipped & "</b></td></tr>"
 Response.Write "</td>"
 Response.Write "</tr>"
 Response.Write "</table>"
 Response.Write "</td>"
 Response.Write "<td>"
 Response.Write "<table cellpadding=5>"
 Response.Write "<tr align=center>" 
 Response.Write "<td>"
 Response.Write "<b>Total Shippers:</b>"
 Response.Write "</td>"
 Response.Write "<td>"
 Response.Write "<b>Total Line Items Shipped:</b>"
 Response.Write "</td>"
 Response.Write "<td>"
 Response.Write "<b>Total Quantity Items Shipped:</b>"
 Response.Write "</td>"
 Response.Write "<td>"
 Response.Write "<b>Configured Kits Shipped:</b>"
 Response.Write "</td></tr>"
Set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 oConn.Open "Driver={SQL Server}; Server=ABSQL21; Database=DF_WHSE; Uid=ReadOnlyUser; Pwd=bionics;"
 Set oRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
 Set oRS2 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

 oRS.open "Select s.ShipDate, Count(distinct CASE when s.country='USA' then l.ShipmentNo end) as TotalShippers, " & _
   "count(case when s.country='USA' then convert(int,l.ShipmentLineNo) END) as TotalLinesShipped, " & _
   "sum(case when s.country='USA' then (l.TotalShippedQuantity) END) as TotalItemsShipped, " & _
   "Count(distinct CASE when s.country<>'USA' then l.ShipmentNo end) as IntlTotalShippers, " & _
   "count(case when s.country<>'USA' then convert(int,l.ShipmentLineNo) END) as IntlTotalLinesShipped, " & _
   "sum(case when s.country<>'USA' then (l.TotalShippedQuantity) else 0 END) as IntlTotalItemsShipped " & _
   "From shipments s, shipments_li l " & _
   "Where (s.ShipDate between '" & D1 & "' AND '" & D2 & "') " & _
   "and  s.ShipmentNo = l.ShipmentNo " & _
   "and l.TotalShippedQuantity>0 and s.status<>'X' AND " & _
   "s.shipfrominventory not in ('BI','CI','CS','IT')" & _
   "Group by s.ShipDate order by s.ShipDate", oConn
 
 
 DO WHILE NOT oRS.EOF
 Response.Write "<tr align=center>"
 Response.Write "<td>" & oRS("IntlTotalShippers").value & "</td>"
 Response.Write "<td>" & oRS("IntlTotalLinesShipped").value & "</td>"
 Response.Write "<td>" & oRS("IntlTotalItemsShipped").value & "</td>"

 oRS2.open "SELECT s.ShipDate, count(case when s.country='USA' THEN (l.ShipmentLineNo) end) AS CountOfKits, " & _
    "count(case when s.country<>'USA' THEN (l.ShipmentLineNo) end) AS IntlCountOfKits " & _
    "FROM (shipments s INNER JOIN shipments_li l ON s.ShipmentNo = l.ShipmentNo) " & _
    "WHERE (l.TotalShippedQuantity>0) AND (s.Status<>'x') " & _
    "AND s.ShipDate='" & oRS("ShipDate").Value & "' " & _
    "AND (Left(l.partNo,5)<>'hires') AND (l.PartDescription<>'CHARGER KIT, AURIA') " & _
    "AND (Left(l.partNo,8) NOT IN ('303-M220' , '303-M218','303-M219')) " & _
    "AND (Left(l.partNo,4)<>'zeni') AND (Left(l.partNo,2)<>'sw') and (Left(l.partNo,7)<>'sr3upus')" & _ 
    "and l.Configuration is not null AND  s.shipfrominventory not in ('BI','CI','CS','IT')" & _
    "GROUP BY s.ShipDate " & _
    "ORDER By s.ShipDate", oConn

IF oRS2.EOF THEN Response.Write "<td>" & 0 & "</td></tr>" ELSE 
DO WHILE NOT oRS2.EOF


 Response.Write "<td>" & oRS2("IntlCountOfKits").Value & "</td></tr>"
 IntlTotalKitsShipped = CInt(oRS2("IntlCountofKits").Value) + IntlTotalKitsShipped
 IntlTotalShippers = CInt(oRS("IntlTotalShippers").Value) + IntlTotalShippers
 IntlTotalShipperLines = CInt(oRS("IntlTotalLinesShipped").Value) + IntlTotalShipperLines
 IntlTotalQuantityShipped = CInt(oRS("IntlTotalItemsShipped").Value) + IntlTotalQuantityShipped
 GrandTotalShippers = TotalShippers + IntlTotalShippers
 GrandTotalShipperLines = TotalShipperLines + IntlTotalShipperLines
 GrandTotalQuantityShipped = TotalQuantityShipped + IntlTotalQuantityShipped
 GrandTotalKitsShipped = IntlTotalKitsShipped + TotalKitsShipped  

 oRS2.MoveNext
 Loop
 oRS2.Close

 oRS.MoveNext
 Loop
 oRS.Close
 Set oRS2 = Nothing   
 Set oRS = Nothing
 oConn.Close
 Set oConn = Nothing 
 Response.Write "<tr align=center>"
 Response.Write "<td><b>" & IntlTotalShippers & "</b></td>"
 Response.Write "<td><b>" & IntlTotalShipperLines & "</b></td>"
 Response.Write "<td><b>" & IntlTotalQuantityShipped & "</b></td>"
 Response.Write "<td><b>" & IntlTotalKitsShipped & "</b></td></tr>"
 Response.Write "</td></tr></table></td></tr>"
 Response.Write "<tr align=center><td colspan=2><table><tr align=center><td>"
 Response.Write "<b>Grand Total Shippers:</b>"
 Response.Write "</td>"
 Response.Write "<td>"
 Response.Write "<b>Grand Total Line Items Shipped:</b>"
 Response.Write "</td>"
 Response.Write "<td>"
 Response.Write "<b>Grand Total Quantity Items Shipped:</b>"
 Response.Write "</td>"
 Response.Write "<td>"
 Response.Write "<b>Grand Total Configured Kits Shipped:</b>"
 Response.Write "</td></tr>"
 Response.Write "<tr align=center>"
 Response.Write "<td><b>" & GrandTotalShippers & "</b></td>"
 Response.Write "<td><b>" & GrandTotalShipperLines & "</b></td>"
 Response.Write "<td><b>" & GrandTotalQuantityShipped & "</b></td>"
 Response.Write "<td><b>" & GrandTotalKitsShipped & "</b></td></tr>"
 Response.Write "</td></tr></table>"
ELSE
END IF
%>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You've shared some login information in that connection string that you might want to strip out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm curious how you were able to determine figures were left out of the total since you already admitting knowing little about how it works.

The one thing that jumps out is the `COUNT(DISTINCT)` on that column. Doing that aggregation day by day and then totaling is likely to give a higher number than aggregating across the entire set all at once. I'm guessing that's where the problem is.

As a second guess, this code is odd to me. Why does it loop over oRS2 but repeatedly add values from oRS?

```
DO WHILE NOT oRS2.EOF
    Response.Write "<td>" & oRS2("CountOfKits").Value & "</td></tr>"
    TotalKitsShipped = CInt(oRS2("CountofKits").Value) + TotalKitsShipped

    TotalShippers = CInt(oRS("TotalShippers").Value) + TotalShippers
    TotalShipperLines = CInt(oRS("TotalLinesShipped").Value) + TotalShipperLines
    TotalQuantityShipped = CInt(oRS("TotalItemsShipped").Value) + TotalQuantityShipped
    oRS2.MoveNext
LOOP
```

Comment: True, perhaps it is working correctly and I am reviewing whatever I can to determine if the coding is incorrect or there is an alternative, however, since the values displayed per day do not add to the total value this is what I need to correct if possible.

Comment: In regards to the distinct, would you suggest adding another oRS based on the shipment table alone since each shipment # is unique?  With the join to the shipment line item table, any shipments with more than one line item would result in duplicates of shipper #'s which is why the distinct is necessary for this column alone.

Comment: I was just looking at it closer and I'm confident the `COUNT(DISTINCT...)` expressions are ok. But I do seriously think the the totaling inside the loops is a problem. Notice how the grand totals are inside a loop as well. The grand totals aren't broken but it shows me that the original writer didn't know what was going on. I would move all the oRS totaling outside of the oRS2 loops. See where that takes you.

Comment: Thank you I will give it a try and post the results.

Comment: Changed as suggested to the below and that appears to have been the culprit, appreciate your quick responses!  `Response.Write "<td>" & oRS2("CountOfKits").Value & "</td></tr>"
 TotalKitsShipped = CInt(oRS2("CountofKits").Value) + TotalKitsShipped

 oRS2.MoveNext
 Loop
 oRS2.Close

 TotalShippers = CInt(oRS("TotalShippers").Value) + TotalShippers
 TotalShipperLines = CInt(oRS("TotalLinesShipped").Value) + TotalShipperLines
 TotalQuantityShipped = CInt(oRS("TotalItemsShipped").Value) + TotalQuantityShipped

 oRS.MoveNext
 Loop
 oRS.Close`